# nullpointerexception when checking if user is logged in

Tags: java, android, authentication, nullpointerexception, dialog

I'm trying to check if the user has logged on before/ is still logged in since he has last left the app.

Now if I start up the app for the first time it gives the force stop error.

But then when I click ok, it just continues to the login screen.

to check if the user is loggedin or not i am ussing a 'if else'

**MainActivity.java oncreate where i check if user is logged on**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
   // user already logged in show databoard
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        finish();

        return;
    }
```

**logcat**

```
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585): Process: info.androidhive.listviewfeed, PID: 30585
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity              ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.listviewfeed/com.BijCasperApp.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at com.BijCasperApp.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
10-14 15:31:33.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30585):    ... 11 more
```

why do I get a nullpointerexception when starting the app?

Comment: Have you tried to debug ?

Comment: have you looked at line 34 .. or let me be more specific, only show code where is the problem, try to minimize code. no one wants to look at 100 lines of code

Comment: Something at line 103 is `null`. Also, the pictures of a force close probably aren't necessary or helpful...we all have seen plenty of them ;)

Comment: line 34 is a comment im afraid @lordkian
will be editting post with these new inputs given

Answer (score 1):

You've commented out the `finish()` from the "not logged in" branch. Put it back and also add a `return`.

Code execution goes on after the if-else and there you're accessing views with `findViewById()` but you only call `setContentView()` in the "logged in" branch. Therefore `findViewById()` returns null and calling a method on null causes the NPE.

Comment: +1 great tip, im affraid even after i set a setContentView() and a return, it still comes back null in the end.